# Run command to untar file in timestamped folder?

Tags: backup, cron, directory, tar, path

I have a .tar file that is transferred to our server every night by one of our client management systems. The file is a compressed .sql file which I need to uncompress and dump into our database.

The directory of the .tar file is `/root/backups/premvet_sync/2012.07.17.10.09.19`. As you can see the directory is a timestamp of when the file was uploaded to our server.

I am trying to create a cron job that CD's into the directory and then uncompresses it. The command I would usually use is something like this:

`cd /root/backups/premvet_sync/2012.07.17.10.09.19 && tar -xvf backupfile.tar`

Obviously that command would only run once (when the timestamp matches the cron job path). Is there anything I can do to CD into the newest directory?

The server is running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS if that makes any difference.

**Update**

For anyone who is interested, here is the final (working) bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Untar backup database and dump into local mysql server.

echo "Finding latest backup directory"
dir=$(ls -td1 /root/backups/backup/* | head -1)

echo "Opening latest backup directory"
cd $dir

echo "Uncompress backup
tar -xvf backup.tar

echo "Dig down into correct directory"
cd $dir/backup/databases/MySQL

echo "mysqldump the compressed database file"
gunzip < backup.sql.gz | mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD restore_db_name

echo "Done."
```

Comment: You could probably do with some sort of test to ensure that the sending side has done it's job before continuing. Perhaps check to see if the  `$dir/backup/databases/MySQL` exists before running the tar command. If it does then the sending side didn't work ...

Comment: Good idea, I presume I can just set it to halt if the directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ls -t` to list the contents of `/root/backups/premvet_sync/` in newest first order then pass that to head to get the first line

```
dir=$(ls -td1 /root/backups/premvet_sync/* | head -1)
```

will put `/root/backups/premvet_sync/2012.07.17.10.09.19` in `$dir` so you can then

```
cd $dir
```

- -t  sort by modification time
- -1  list one file per line
- -d  list directory entries instead of contents, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`

mkdir -p /some/dir/$DATE

cd /some/dir/$DATE
```

etc

Comment: That doesn't produce a filename in the OPs stated format. As this is running after the file has been uploaded any portion of the date could be different from when it was created.